# What exactly Ciris.ConfigDecoder does in scala

Tags: scala, type-conversion

I am new to scala and trying to support an application written in scala using ciris package.
I want to understand the is ciris ConfigDecoder and what the below code is trying to do.

```
@inline implicit def sourceTopicsConfigDecoder(implicit ev: ConfigDecoder[String, NonEmptyString]): ConfigDecoder[String, SourceTopics] =
    ev.map(_.value.split(",").toSet.map(NonEmptyString.unsafeFrom)) map SourceTopics.apply

  @inline implicit val sourceTopicsShow: Show[SourceTopics] =
    _.unMk.mkString(",")
```

Comment: How much of this do you understand and what level of detail are you looking for?

Comment: i want to understand what is this implicit function is doing and why it is defined . also about the use of configdecoder with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used (or even heard of) Ciris before, but a quick visit to the [documentation](https://cir.is/docs/overview) informs me that `ConfigDecoder` is the means by which the received configuration type (usually a `String`) is cast to a more useful type. Something like: `env("SIZE_LIMIT").as[Long]`

I also learned that, while many useful `ConfigDecoder`s are supplied, you can also make your own for decoding configuration values into application specific types, and that's what `sourceTopicsConfigDecoder` appears to be doing. It pulls an existing `String`-to-`NonEmptyString` decoder from the implicit scope and uses it to build a `String`-to-`SourceTopics` decoder. (`SourceTopics` must be previously defined.)

The new decoder is made implicit so that elsewhere in the code you can do something like: `env("SRC_TOPICS").as[SourceTopics]`

Comment: Thanks jwvh , i got few ideas from your answer. could you please help me to understand more with an example please.

Comment: @roshanpanda; Have you reviewed the documentation? In particular, [this part](https://cir.is/docs/configurations#decoders) about decoders? Your post is an example of creating a decoder. My post ends with an example of invoking that decoder. It isn't invoked directly because `sourceTopicsConfigDecoder` is implicit. If you're unsure how implicits work I suggest you find a good Scala tutorial.